# Handling long menu in TCL

Tags: menu, tcl, tk-toolkit

I have an old TCL app that has a menu that isn't displaying all the entries.

How can I create a multi-column menu or a scrolling menu so all menu entries can be seen?

This is TCL v8.0

This is for a gui.

The code fragment I'm looking at is:

```
#
# Setup the folder Menu
#
menubutton $w.folder -text Folder -menu $w.folder.menu
menu $w.folder.menu -tearoff 0
$w.folder.menu add command -label "New"      -command createNewFolder -state disabled
$w.folder.menu add command -label "Open"     -command openFolder 
$w.folder.menu add command -label "Delete"   -command deleteFolder -state disabled
$w.folder.menu add command -label "Printer Setup" -command selectPrinter -state  disabled
$w.folder.menu add command -label "Quit"     -command xqmQuit 
$w.folder.menu add separator
foreach queue $privateGlobals(folderList) {
   $w.folder.menu add command -label "$queue" -command [list openFolder "$queue"]
}
```

What is happening is that in the foreach loop there are a lot of entries that get created but I can only see about 46 out of 60 or 80.

I haven't done TCL in a long time but I didn't see any obvious options in the menu widget to do what I wanted.

Comment: Is it a GUI menu or text menu? It helps if you would post relevant section of your code. Also, what have you tried?

Comment: If it's a really large set of options to choose between, consider using a different UI technique. Menus don't scale up well to many hundreds of items, which is really a limitation of how _people_ are more (and what size displays are) than anything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [-columnbreak value](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/menu.htm#M32) option.

```
set i 0
foreach queue $privateGlobals(folderList) {
   $w.folder.menu add command -label "$queue" -command [list openFolder "$queue"] -columnbreak [expr $i % 10 == 0]
   incr i
}
```

Comment: I totally misread the man page regarding columnbreak. Thanks mucho.